# Stuck in Android SDK Manager API 19 installation

Tags: android, sdk

Is there anybody who knows why this problem occurs ? I am really stuck in this problem. It is so stupid condition,isn't it ?[image]

Comment: The bar at the bottom of your second screenshot shows that there was six minutes left in the download process. Have you tried it and allowed it to actually complete?

Comment: I noticed that i have different sdk paths. why does android use so many paths :S

Comment: I cannot read those SDK paths, sorry.

Comment: Thanks my friend :) i had stupid problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is you have 2 sdk on your computer and each has it's own platforms

see `SDK Path` on top of your sdk manager

Comment: thanks i noticed that. i was so angry when i wrote this question. Therefore i couldn't realize it. why does it use different paths :S

Comment: please accept my answer if it solved your problem :)

sdk manager is in bundle with sdk and other tools for android and you have downloaded or copied sdk multiple times in different locations.

Comment: i will accept but i have to wait about 8 minutes to do that

Comment: `why does it use different paths` it doesn't, you have installed it twice to different locations.